# Powershell not using my variable in command

Tags: powershell

I have this bit of simple code where I am passed a variable for the username, I need to parse that and then use it in a path for a copy command.
I have used outputting the variables to a text file to help try to troubleshoot the problem.

I parse the variable, and it seems to output to the text file properly, but when I use it in my path variable it shows as empty.

The Code:

```
param ([String] $mdmUserName)

$mdmUserName | Out-File "C:\Windows\Temp\test.txt"
$FullUserSplit = $mdmUserName.Split("\")
$FullUserSplit | Out-File -append "C:\Windows\Temp\test.txt"
$localusername = $FullUserSplit[2]
$localusername | Out-File -Append "C:\Windows\Temp\test.txt"

$from = "C:\Windows\Temp\Normaltest.dotm"
$to = "C:\Users\$localusername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\"

$to | Out-File -Append "C:\Windows\Temp\test.txt"

Copy-Item $from $to -Force
```

The output of the test.txt file:

```
Win11\User
Win11
User
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\
```

You can see that it outputs the $localusername variable correctly to the test.txt, but then when added to the path it is not there. I feel like I am missing something simple.

I also tried manually setting the $mdmusername manually to "Win11/User" with the same result.

Comment: Arrays are zero based (they start with `0`), thus: `$FullUserSplit[1]` or `$FullUserSplit[-1]` (which selects the last entry)

Comment: Lol, I feel like an idiot, I knew it was something simple I was overlooking.

Comment: Please post iRon's answer as an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Arrays are zero based (they start with 0), thus: $FullUserSplit[1] or $FullUserSplit[-1] (which selects the last entry) – iRon

iRon's comment was the answer. I needed to use $FullUserSplit[1]

Outputting the $FullUserSplit to the troubleshooting file was throwing me off, as it outputted the full array on 2 lines.